# Difference between EXISTS and JOIN to check existence of records

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join, exists

Looking at the following example:

```
SELECT *
FROM customers
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT *
     FROM order_details
     WHERE customers.customer_id = order_details.customer_id)
;
```

Which differences are there from an equivalent `inner join`-based query between the two tables that retrieves the same resultset?

I'm concerned about the technical/performance aspect, not the readability/mantainabilty of the code.

Comment: The JOIN may produce duplicates.

Comment: In addition to previous comment, a join with a select * will return all the fields from both tables, instead of just customers which will be the returned data in your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EXISTS would be logically working as follows

```
for x in (select * from customers)
loop
      -- check if x.customer_id exists in order_details table.    
      ---if yes 
          --output the customer tables row
      -- else 
         --ignore 
end if;
end loop;
```

So in the exists query the plan would generally be using a nested loop(Not a hard-fast rule though)

The JOIN query does the logical equivalent as follows

```
for x in (select * from customers)
loop
  --for each row in customer 
  -- fetch records from order_details which match this condition
      select * from order_details where customer_id=x.customerid     
end loop;
```

Comment: If you statistics is updated in customers and order_details i wouldnt necessarily worry about the performance of EXISTS over JOIN. SQL is a declarative language, the work of trying to find out "how" to get the data is best left to the optimizer. As users of SQL we should be thinking of the logical and semantic well formedness of a query

Answer (score 3):

With an `EXISTS` clause you select all customers for which exist at least one order_details record.

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM order_details od WHERE od.customer_id = c.customer_id);
```

With a join you'd select again those customers. However, you'd select each as often as there exists an order_detail for them. I.e. you'd have many duplicates.

```
SELECT c.*
FROM customers c
JOIN order_details od ON c.customer_id = od.customer_id;
```

You can remove the duplicates from your results with `DISTINCT` so as to get each customer only once again:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.*
FROM customers c
JOIN order_details od ON c.customer_id = od.customer_id;
```

But why generate all the duplicates only to have to remove them again? Don't do this. Only join when you really want joined results.

Another option, which I consider even more readable than an `EXISTS` clause is the `IN` clause by the way. This would be my way of writing the query:

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customer_id IN (SELECT customer_id FROM order_details);
```

Comment: I think `EXISTS` is more readable and more easily optimized.  Plus, it discourages use of `NOT IN` with a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

`EXISTS()` is called a "semi-join".  It starts a `JOIN`, but then stops when it finds the first match.  For this reason, `EXISTS` will be faster than any equivalent `JOIN`.

Also, `EXISTS( SELECT * ... WHERE ... )` does not really care about the `*`.  It will use whatever index is optimal to discover the presence or absence  of rows matching the `WHERE`, then it returns 1 or 0 (meaning "true" or "false").

Of course, if a `LEFT JOIN` is going to return 0 or 1 row, never more, then there is not much performance difference.  Except that the `LEFT JOIN` will return values from the table.